# Minimum cell height - Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have some *Autolayout* Cells - but would like that they have a minimum height, if the second Label does not contain any text (for example in an form)

I thought the easiest way should be to create an additional Constraint with Priority 999 to setup an minimum height, like in that pic:

[image]

But then, the label ("Mayer Thomas") is not self-sizing anymore.

Whats the best way to solve such things? I could create 2 layouts, but in my opinion that should be not a good solution.

Comment: why don't you expand the cell height in code when the label has a value and do the opposite when it doesn't

Comment: That was an idea (check out my last sentence) - but i got a few layouts, so i need to make multiple "new" layouts without that labels in bottom. Thats why i am asking for an better, easier way.

Comment: Have you set the constraint to be `>=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height constraint of the optional label as *greater than or equal to* whatever height you want. Also, set the *compression resistance* and *content hugging* of the label to required. Your label should now consume extra height if there is more content, or just take the minimum size that was set.

```
[label addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:15/*the min height you need*/]];
[label setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[label setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

Answer (score 0):

For that You need to use EqualHeights and change the multiplier accordingly they will self-Size themselves .

To do that just CTRL+Drag the label onto the cell gives equal heights and change the multiplier it will be 1 change it to whatever value you want. Eg: - 0.5 means it will take half the height of the cell.